# Show that no random variable exists which has a kurtosis which is strictly less than 1

Tags: statistics

Show that no random variable exists which has a kurtosis which is strictly less than 1.
The kurtosis has the following formula:$\frac{E[(X-\mu _{X})^4]]}{(E[(X-\mu _{X})^2])^2}$

Can anyone help me proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Put $\xi = (X- \mu_X)^2$. We know that $D\xi \ge 0$ and hence $E\xi^2 \ge (E\xi)^2$. Q.e.d.